# Footnotes inside a grid_table in pandoc

Tags: pandoc, footnotes

I am rendering markdown through pandoc+pdflatex. I'd like to have footnote marks inside of a table (grid_table), with footnote text appearing in the bottom of the page. I did:

```
+-----------------+-------+---------+
|property         | A     | B       |
+=================+=======+=========+
|a                |   x   |   y[^1] |
+-----------------+-------+---------+
[^1]: blah blah
```

But what I got instead was the footnote being rendered **inside the cell** of the table. How do I get (expected, I think) behavior, where the footnote is being rendered at the bottom of the page?

Comment: I have realized the problem is with the generated LaTeX code - grid tables create minipages, and footnote can't escape it. The solutions are discussed here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3028/is-there-a-reliable-footnote-command